Is there a way to automatically assign conversations to the user who replied to them in google groups?
I was able to configure my google group to act like a shared mailbox. Basically I have each of the group members set up a "send mail as" in their Gmail settings to the group address. That way, when replying to a conversation sent to the group from clients, they may reply from the group address rather than their personal address.
What I am now looking for is a way to block conversation replies until the conversation has been assigned. OR For a way to have the conversations assigned automatically to the user who is replying to the conversation.
I'm sorry if my question is a bit wordy, please let me know if I can clarify.
Thanks in advance for your expertise. 
I tried looking in group settings but there are no options for my request.
I have also searched for answers elsewhere but couldn't find anything, so I am hoping someone else has figured this out before.
